# OSGI bundle version of SWT 4.4.2

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, osgi-bundle

A project we are working on uses SWT (Version 3.8.1 that shipped with a old version of eclipse).

I want to upgrade to SWT 4.4.2, which is downloadable from the eclipse site. But I need the OSGI bundle version of 4.4.2 as our project previously used OSGI version of the SWT jars. The version supplied on the eclipse site is not an OSGI bundle.

Where can I get an OSGI bundle version of SWT 4.4.2?

Thanks

Alan

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Eclipse Project Downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) site. The SWT download there still gives you just the jars so you have to download something like the 'Platform Runtime Binary' build which will contain the SWT plugins.

Note: For Eclipse 4.4.2 the SWT version is 3.103.2, for Eclipse 4.5.1 it is 3.104.1